# Table Level Encryption

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds

I've been playing with RDS recently and wondering if it's possible to get table level encryption on RDS instances?

I can see that there's support for encryption in SQL Server before data is written to storage and decryption when it's being read from storage, but is it possible to have encryption down to tables?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What would be the benefit of that?  If the entire DB is encrypted the table is encrypted.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible. I suppose table level encryption would automatically come in once the entire DB is encrypted.